# VLAN routing on the same subnet

Tags: routing, vlan, ipv4, interface

Consider following situation:

You have `10.3.0.0/16` network without any VLANs. Now You want to divide it...

You want Your IT department be able to reach the entire network, but sales department only Domain Controller, printers etc. You want IP cameras would be reachable only by security and managers.. I think You've got the idea.

Question: Am I getting it right that it is not possible that all hosts stay in same subnet, but each host will now belong to some VLAN, and the "routing" between VLANs will be done via Layer 3 switches. If not how it can be done?

P.S. I know that it can be done if You divide `10.3.0.0/16` to smaller subnets.

Thank You.

Comment: You need a router to route traffic between VLANs, and each router interface must be in a different network. Using the same network on multiple router interfaces means that a router would have to guess how to forward packets, but routers are deterministic and cannot guess. You simply subnet the network and assign one of the subnets to each VLAN, then you can control access with ACLs.

Comment: @RonMaupin I have only one router and it is default gateway for all hosts on the network.

Comment: The router will still be the default, but the router interfaces for each VLAN will have an address in the VLAN, and that will be the gateway for that VLAN. This is routing 101, and it is done all the time.

Comment: @RonMaupin You mean Router-On-the-Stick?

Comment: That is one way, or you connect separate router interfaces to separate switch interfaces that are in different VLANs.

Comment: @RonMaupin May be I don't understand, but for example I have 1000 VLANs. Will Your suggestion work? The question is.. in the question  is it possible via L3 switches? Without dealing with cables?

Comment: Layer-3 switches have a built-in router, so you will be using that router, but then, your existing will no longer be the gateway. You will need to either statically configure routes to the network behind the router in the layer-3 switch, or you will need to configure both with a common routing protocol to exchange routing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is not possible that all hosts stay in same subnet

That is correct. VLANs segregate your network into multiple layer-2 segments and connecting it back together mandates different subnets for proper routing. Likely, you'd want to split your inital 10.3.0.0/16 network into subnets.

> but each host will now belong to some VLAN

Yes, each host needs to belong to *some* VLAN. It's not possible to connect to the switch without using a VLAN. If you don't configure VLANs, there's a single *default* VLAN that all ports are untagged members of.

> and the "routing" between VLANs will be done via Layer 3 switches.

Yes.

On a layer-3 switch, you can bind an IP address to a VLAN (*switch virtual interface* SVI) or to a layer-3 interface (`interface <port>` and `no switchport`), depending on the switch model. The attached hosts can then use that address from their VLAN as gateway. If you use the VLANs as security zones you also need to set up ACLs to control the inter-VLAN traffic as required.